# Playsound module acting strange

Tags: python, python-playsound

I've been using the Python playsound module to play audio, and in VScode it works great, but when I play it outside of VScode in the console instead of the audio playing like usual, I get an error saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound'
```

I write in `from playsound import playsound` to import the module, and if I just try and write, `import playsound`, it doesn't even work in VScode, saying *"'module' object is not callable"*.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the new version, uninstalled and reinstalled version 1.2.2, and I'm beginning to lose hope with playsound. Has anyone out there experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

At first, second part of your question:
You cannot just

```
import playsound

playsound(...)
```

because playsound is a module in this case, which is not callable (as the interpreter told you).
you need to import function playsound from the module, that is why

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound(...)
```

works.

First part of your question:
It might be possible vscode is using another version of python from one you're calling from the command line. Without more information about your environment setup I can only guess. Try to do this:

```
$ python -m pip install playsound
```

then

```
$ python -m playsound "path-to-your-mp3-file.mp3"
```

that should work without a problem.

Comment: I just read on another post to use just "import playsound" also when I run the commands, the first one, I get this error: "error: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe: No module named pip" and when I run the second command I get this: "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe: No module named playsound" I see that the file path for both of those are where I got my c/c++ compiler, and I do remember changing some settings so I can type "G++ --version" on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was causing the problem. I had to edit the environment variables that point to pip and it started to work again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).